# Sin(m°) is algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

In problem 15, section 5.1 from Herstein, we have to show that $\sin(1°)$ is algebraic and this part is ok. But i don't know how to use this to show that for all $m$ integer $\sin(m°)$ is algebraic too and the statement suggests this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\sin 1$ is algebraic, so is $\cos 1$.  Use induction and the sum of angles formula.